Polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ has all non real roots
Let $f\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $f$ is irreducible and $a\in \mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{R}$ be its root. Assume $\mathbb{Q}(a)|\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois. I want to show all roots of $f$ are non real. I have no idea where to proceed, I only know if $\sigma\in \text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(a)|\mathbb{Q})$, then $\sigma(a)$ is also root of $f$, but I cannot show $\sigma(a)$ should also be non real.

all embeddings of a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ have the same image in $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$.  If one image is non-real, so are the others.  That would be the argument.

@orangeskid thank you.
